# pip fails to find brew installed libs with M1 chip

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, apple-m1

folks, with new **M1 chip** brew stores its libraries in the **different location** `/opt/homebrew/` instead of `/usr/local/`.
And now when **pip needs** some packages installed by **brew**(in my case `leveldb` for `plyvel`)it's not able to find it until I use **Rosetta brew** version to put in the old directory: `/usr/local/`.
I've added `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in my `.zshrc` to import brew-related vars and I thought it should do the thing but no lack.

Do you have any tips on how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether there is a Right Way to do this, but one way is to pass the necessary compiler flags as an environment variable:

```
CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib" python3 -m pip install plyvel
```

Comment: This solution did not work as CFLAGS are only used during compilation and hence library path was not used.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution to this problem is to include homebrew path in `LDFLAGS`

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib/
```

and then run the pip command. It is best to add this to your bash / zsh profile (`~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc`).